# Printing in Java - Printable.print() resizes images

Tags: java, printing

I have a custom report which draws via `Graphics2D`, and uses a lot of tiny `BufferedImage` sprites. `PrinterJob.print()` seems to be calling `Printable.print()` roughly once for each sprite (the actual count can vary both ways), so some pages are re-rendered 150 times... This causes printing to be unacceptably slow, about 10 seconds for two pages.

I found this: [Why does the java Printable's print method get called multiple times with the same page number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943556/why-does-the-java-printables-print-method-get-called-multiple-times-with-the-sa)

But it doesn't appear to explain my particular problem (or only partially explains it). I created a test report which has only a few sprites, and there was a small number of resizes that went up and down as I added and removed images on either the vertical or horizontal axes.

When printing to a PDF using Bullzip, I noticed that after zooming in on the images, they are being scaled up using a bilinear or bicubic algorithm. One of these images, which is unique in having an indexed color palette, does not appear to be scaled. I confirmed that the scaling is a Java behavior and not being performed by Bullzip by printing to a real printer and observing the same images being scaled versus not.

So it strikes me as the print API trying to rescale images to whatever DPI it has in mind, but for some reason it's calling `Printable.print()` each time it encounters an image that it deems as needing this treatment.

How do I fix this behavior? I tried setting rendering hints on the `Graphics2D` that I get when `Printable.print()` is called, to no avail. I don't know what else to do short of try to find and examine the print API's source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just figured it out by accident. A report I just modified now draws an image over some geometry, and I noticed that the part of the geometry that's behind the box of the image is being rasterized and looks blurry compared to outside of the box. The image in question (and all other than the one indexed color image) has an 8 bit alpha channel.

I noticed before that Java's print rasterizer doesn't like things with translucency (one report which used it was being completely rasterized at I think 300dpi...), but I forgot that these images also had alpha channels.

When I get a chance, I'm probably going to fix this by further increasing the images' resolution and using 1 bit alpha. When scaled down for screen viewing, it will have a few bits of alpha again and look okay.